# python flask website error: the requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, flask

I have wrote my first flask program, which logs into my device via telnet and gives me the output of a cat command. But I always get the error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. 
If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

This call of the function GetLogs does not work (doesn't even come into the function - tried it with a print() within the function to see)

```
@app.route('/GetLogs/<name>&path=<path>/')
def GetLogs(name, path):
    tempStr=''
    HOST = name
    user = "root"
    password = "password"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, timeout=5)
    tn.read_until(b"login: ")
    time.sleep(1)
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.read_until(b'Password: ')
    time.sleep(1)
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    PATH_TO_LOG = "cat " + path + "\n"
    tn.write(PATH_TO_LOG.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.write(b"exit\n")
    tempStr=tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
    return tempStr.replace("\r\n", "<br />")
```

The other function Unlock works with basically the same code for app.route(...) but with only 1 parameter

```
@app.route('/Unlock/<name>/')
def Unlock(name):
    return "unlocked"
```

Here is the rest of the code, that adds a small HTML UI with 2 textfields and 2 buttons:

```
@app.route('/')
def main_form():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <br><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Buttons" value="Unlock">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Buttons" value="GetLogs"><input type="text" name="LogText">
        <br><br>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
'''


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ExecuteButtons():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       inputtext = request.form['text']
       inputtext = inputtext.replace("http://", "")
       inputtext = inputtext.replace("/","")
       inputtext = inputtext.replace(".com","")
       if request.form['Buttons'] == 'Unlock':
          #inputtext = request.form['text']
          return redirect(url_for('Unlock', name = inputtext))
       elif request.form['Buttons'] == 'GetLogs':
          #inputtext = request.form['text']
          return redirect(url_for('GetLogs', name = inputtext, path=request.form['LogText']))
```

The URL gets generated right with name = chosenName and path = /var/log/messages* |head -10: `http://something.com:5001/GetLogs/chosenName%26path%3D/var/log/messages%2A%20%7Chead%20-10/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "/" being provided in the GetLogs are creating issues.

I changed them with "%" before providing the path to the GetLogs function and it worked.

Again replace it with "/" once you fed the path to your function.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ExecuteButtons():
  if request.method == 'POST':
       inputtext = request.form['text']
       inputtext = inputtext.replace("http://", "")
       inputtext = inputtext.replace("/","")
       inputtext = inputtext.replace(".com","")
       if request.form['Buttons'] == 'Unlock':
          #inputtext = request.form['text']
          return redirect(url_for('Unlock', name = inputtext))
       elif request.form['Buttons'] == 'GetLogs':
          #inputtext = request.form['text']
          abspath=request.form['LogText'].replace("/","%")
          print(abspath)
          return redirect(url_for('GetLogs', name = inputtext, path=abspath))

@app.route('/GetLogs/<name>&<path>/')
def GetLogs(name, path):
  abspath=path.replace("%","")
  return "works"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

[image: After the code change]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it might be related to how you access the query string. Your path variable should be accessed with `request.args.get()`.

```
@app.route('/GetLogs/<name>')
def GetLogs(name):
    path = request.args.get("path")
    tempStr=''
    HOST = name
    user = "root"
    password = "password"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, timeout=5)
    tn.read_until(b"login: ")
    time.sleep(1)
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.read_until(b'Password: ')
    time.sleep(1)
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    PATH_TO_LOG = "cat " + path + "\n"
    tn.write(PATH_TO_LOG.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.write(b"exit\n")
    tempStr=tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
    return tempStr.replace("\r\n", "<br />")
```

Comment: Thanks, works this way. But is there a way to make it work within the URL? When I think about webpages there is often the possibility to type the URL http://something.com/chosenName&path="/var/log/messages" for example so you can navigate either over the button or the URL. With the Unlock Script it works - when i navigate to the url .../Unlock/chosenName it starts the script with chosenName

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking could you clarify further?

Comment: the answer from Vignesh SP is what I asked for - both work